# Python - IPython Notebook fails to find the Java executable

Tags: java, python, windows, jupyter-notebook, executable-jar

I am using IPython Notebook on Windows 7 which needs to call Java executables (.jar)

I set JAVA_HOME to 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/bin' where my jdk is installed, but when I run the program I get the error "... unable to find the java executable!"

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've found a solution adding those lines to my IPython Notebook

```
import os
java_home = os.environ.get('JAVA_HOME', None)
if not java_home:
    java_path = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/bin'
    os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = java_path
else:
    print(java_home)
```